# How to get data from json in PHP?

Tags: php

I have such `json` data structure:

```
$data='[{"day":0,"periods":[{"start":"01:00","end":"02:00","title":"","backgroundColor":"rgba(254, 0, 0, 0.7)","borderColor":"rgb(42, 60, 255)","textColor":"rgb(0, 0, 0)"},{"start":"02:30","end":"03:00","title":"","backgroundColor":"rgba(254, 0, 0, 0.7)","borderColor":"rgb(42, 60, 255)","textColor":"rgb(0, 0, 0)"}]},{"day":1,"periods":[{"start":"01:00","end":"02:00","title":"","backgroundColor":"rgba(254, 0, 0, 0.7)","borderColor":"rgb(42, 60, 255)","textColor":"rgb(0, 0, 0)"}]},{"day":2,"periods":[{"start":"01:00","end":"01:30","title":"","backgroundColor":"rgba(254, 0, 0, 0.7)","borderColor":"rgb(42, 60, 255)","textColor":"rgb(0, 0, 0)"}]},{"day":3,"periods":[{"start":"02:00","end":"02:30","title":"","backgroundColor":"rgba(254, 0, 0, 0.7)","borderColor":"rgb(42, 60, 255)","textColor":"rgb(0, 0, 0)"}]},{"day":4,"periods":[{"start":"01:00","end":"01:30","title":"","backgroundColor":"rgba(254, 0, 0, 0.7)","borderColor":"rgb(42, 60, 255)","textColor":"rgb(0, 0, 0)"}]},{"day":5,"periods":[{"start":"01:30","end":"02:00","title":"","backgroundColor":"rgba(254, 0, 0, 0.7)","borderColor":"rgb(42, 60, 255)","textColor":"rgb(0, 0, 0)"},{"start":"03:00","end":"03:30","title":"","backgroundColor":"rgba(254, 0, 0, 0.7)","borderColor":"rgb(42, 60, 255)","textColor":"rgb(0, 0, 0)"}]},{"day":6,"periods":[]}]';
```

I want to get all days and start and end time which is in periods.

How to **loop threw array** and get ? It has 7 days day[0]-day[6] and periods is array which can be empty or have values.

day

periods->start

periods->end

Comment: have you tried json_decode?

Comment: This is not valid json! There is an [ missing at the start of the string

Comment: Where do you geht the json string from. Is the opening bracket really missing or is it a typo? If you get the string automated and the is allways the beginning "[" missing, you could use str = "[" . str;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like everyone is saying you need to use [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to decode the json in to a php variable. When you add TRUE to that function, you will get an associative array. However, no one is telling you how to loop through this array.

One way you could do this is by using [foreach()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). Because you have a multidimensional array you'll need to use foreach() multiple times.

```
<?php

$data='[{"day":0,"periods":[{"start":"01:00","end":"02:00","title":"","backgroundColor":"rgba(254, 0, 0, 0.7)","borderColor":"rgb(42, 60, 255)","textColor":"rgb(0, 0, 0)"},{"start":"02:30","end":"03:00","title":"","backgroundColor":"rgba(254, 0, 0, 0.7)","borderColor":"rgb(42, 60, 255)","textColor":"rgb(0, 0, 0)"}]},{"day":1,"periods":[{"start":"01:00","end":"02:00","title":"","backgroundColor":"rgba(254, 0, 0, 0.7)","borderColor":"rgb(42, 60, 255)","textColor":"rgb(0, 0, 0)"}]},{"day":2,"periods":[{"start":"01:00","end":"01:30","title":"","backgroundColor":"rgba(254, 0, 0, 0.7)","borderColor":"rgb(42, 60, 255)","textColor":"rgb(0, 0, 0)"}]},{"day":3,"periods":[{"start":"02:00","end":"02:30","title":"","backgroundColor":"rgba(254, 0, 0, 0.7)","borderColor":"rgb(42, 60, 255)","textColor":"rgb(0, 0, 0)"}]},{"day":4,"periods":[{"start":"01:00","end":"01:30","title":"","backgroundColor":"rgba(254, 0, 0, 0.7)","borderColor":"rgb(42, 60, 255)","textColor":"rgb(0, 0, 0)"}]},{"day":5,"periods":[{"start":"01:30","end":"02:00","title":"","backgroundColor":"rgba(254, 0, 0, 0.7)","borderColor":"rgb(42, 60, 255)","textColor":"rgb(0, 0, 0)"},{"start":"03:00","end":"03:30","title":"","backgroundColor":"rgba(254, 0, 0, 0.7)","borderColor":"rgb(42, 60, 255)","textColor":"rgb(0, 0, 0)"}]},{"day":6,"periods":[]}]';

// Decodes a JSON string, When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays. 
$array = json_decode($data, true);


/* Output array, uncomment if you would like to see
   echo '<pre>' to make it readable */
// echo '<pre>';
// print_r($array);

// foreach lvl in the array we need to use a new foreach() 
foreach($array as $day) {
    echo 'Day: '. $day['day'] .'<br>';

    foreach($day['periods'] as $periodId => $period) {
        echo 'Period '. $periodId .': '. $period['start'] .' - '. $period['end'] .'<br>';
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to parse the data, which is a string, to an object or array using json_encode

```
$data=json_encode('[{"day":0,"periods":[]},{"day":1,"periods":[{"start":"08:00","end":"10:00","title":"","backgroundColor":"rgba(254, 0, 0, 0.7)","borderColor":"rgb(42, 60, 255)","textColor":"rgb(0, 0, 0)"},{"start":"11:00","end":"12:30","title":"","backgroundColor":"rgba(254, 0, 0, 0.7)","borderColor":"rgb(42, 60, 255)","textColor":"rgb(0, 0, 0)"}]},{"day":2,"periods":[{"start":"20:00","end":"00:00","title":"","backgroundColor":"rgba(254, 0, 0, 0.7)","borderColor":"rgb(42, 60, 255)","textColor":"rgb(0, 0, 0)"}]},{"day":3,"periods":[]},{"day":4,"periods":[{"start":"10:00","end":"12:00","title":"","backgroundColor":"rgba(254, 0, 0, 0.7)","borderColor":"rgb(42, 60, 255)","textColor":"rgb(0, 0, 0)"},{"start":"13:00","end":"14:00","title":"","backgroundColor":"rgba(254, 0, 0, 0.7)","borderColor":"rgb(42, 60, 255)","textColor":"rgb(0, 0, 0)"},{"start":"15:00","end":"16:00","title":"","backgroundColor":"rgba(254, 0, 0, 0.7)","borderColor":"rgb(42, 60, 255)","textColor":"rgb(0, 0, 0)"}]},{"day":5,"periods":[]},{"day":6,"periods":[]}]');
```

You can then access it as an object:

```
echo $data[0]->day;
```

The compete documentation is [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Comment: and how to get(access)  periods start and end  ? example day:1 periods[start]="08:00" periods[end]="10:00"

Comment: Periods is an array, so it would be $data[0]->periods[0]->start

Answer (score 1):

you need to decode the json by `json_decode();` something like this.

```
$json = '[{"day":0,"periods":[]},{"day":1,"periods":[{"start":"08:00","end":"10:00","title":"","backgroundColor":"rgba(254, 0, 0, 0.7)","borderColor":"rgb(42, 60, 255)","textColor":"rgb(0, 0, 0)"},{"start":"11:00","end":"12:30","title":"","backgroundColor":"rgba(254, 0, 0, 0.7)","borderColor":"rgb(42, 60, 255)","textColor":"rgb(0, 0, 0)"}]},{"day":2,"periods":[{"start":"20:00","end":"00:00","title":"","backgroundColor":"rgba(254, 0, 0, 0.7)","borderColor":"rgb(42, 60, 255)","textColor":"rgb(0, 0, 0)"}]},{"day":3,"periods":[]},{"day":4,"periods":[{"start":"10:00","end":"12:00","title":"","backgroundColor":"rgba(254, 0, 0, 0.7)","borderColor":"rgb(42, 60, 255)","textColor":"rgb(0, 0, 0)"},{"start":"13:00","end":"14:00","title":"","backgroundColor":"rgba(254, 0, 0, 0.7)","borderColor":"rgb(42, 60, 255)","textColor":"rgb(0, 0, 0)"},{"start":"15:00","end":"16:00","title":"","backgroundColor":"rgba(254, 0, 0, 0.7)","borderColor":"rgb(42, 60, 255)","textColor":"rgb(0, 0, 0)"}]},{"day":5,"periods":[]},{"day":6,"periods":[]}]';
$result = json_decode ($json);
```

And get data like this.

```
echo $result[1]->periods[0]->end;
```

Comment: Nice :) I can get  $result[1]->periods[0]->end; But how to loop threw all array and echo all day,periods[0]->start and periods[0]->end  periods is array too it can have periods[0]->start and periods[1]->start ???